# Windows command to Read text file from specific position

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, command

I am trying to write my first batch file, hence a very simple question:
I have a file (say "myfile.txt") which has names of 10 cities in different rows. I want to print all these names on command prompt one by one, but my only constraint is I don't want first 2 letters of the city names to be displayed, how can I do it?

I tried following code which does not seem to work:

```
    for /F "eol=: tokens=1" %%G in (myfile.txt) do (
    ECHO %%G:~2%
    )
```

Comment: If your goal is to learn native shell scripting on Windows, then I suggest that you skip DOS batch files and check out [tag:powershell] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to temporarily copy the line into a variable, and then get the substring of that. Also you'll want to `enabledelayedexpansion` and change tokens to * (for cities with spaces in them). And turn echo off if you want only the cities output.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "eol=: tokens=*" %%G in (myfile.txt) do (
    set line=%%G
    ECHO !line:~2!
)
```

Comment: what is the use of "enabledelayedexpansion" ?

Comment: i just tried to use your code example, it does seem to be working. but if i use "%" instead of "!" in the last line of the code, it doesn't work. why is that? isn't "%" is valid syntax?

Comment: It enables us to use the `!` instead of `%`, which is best-practice in a for-loop since `%` gets expanded before the loop is run.

Comment: @ArpanKumar,  How so?

Comment: @ArpanKumar, if you are only wanting the cities listed in your output turn echo off. I've updated the code in my answer to do this.

Comment: @Matt, thanks for your help, it does work now. i am still not clear on two things though:
1. why is using variable must here?
2. why does it not work if i use "%" instead of "!" in last line of the code

Comment: 1. The syntax for loop variables doesn't allow for a substring, so you have to copy it to a regular variable. 2. the `%` gets expanded before the for loop is run, whereas the `!` doesn't until it gets executed.

Comment: Note that this is true for any variable that gets declared inside of a code block in batch.